# Adding an sql query to the end of a wordpress permalink?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Ok....so I created a new wordpress theme and I still can't get my custom code to work.

I want to be able to have a page which will output a list of items from the database, each item will have this URL format:

www.site.com/category/subcategory/?id=XX

The ?id=XX query should be at the end of the URL and will direct the user from the category page to the subcategory page showing specific data about the item with the XX id.

Each item in the list is wrapped in an  tag in the category template page and the subcategory page uses $_GET. I've got one wordpress theme that works but on my other site, I use a different theme and it doesn't work. If a user clicks on an item in the list, the user gets directed to the subcategory page without the sql string attached. I'm not sure what to put in the functions.php file in wordpress (or whatever the file is called that handles functions) or in the htaccess. Any help is appreciated.

Update:

@Niels - I didn't make the code...I had two people make the code for me. Neither of them are professional coders but they got it to work so that's all I cared about.  My website has never been hacked before but I need to find out how to get the code to work myself since the two guys who created the code are busy nowadays.  Yea, I've been told about the sql injection.

I've got php code on the category page (http://www.mysite.com/category) that defines variables that will be used in the code, connects to the database, queries the database table, and then selects and outputs the items in the database table using the id of the item.  The code uses a while loop to output the items so that the category page is basically a directory of items.  Each item that gets outputted is outputted in this format: $itemname.  Like I said, the code already defines these variables at the very beginning so the sql query already knows what to look for.  When a user clicks on any item in the category page, the link should take them to the item's profile page, which is basically the subcategory page (ie: http://www.mysite.com/category/subcategory/).  So let me be clear: when a user CLICKS on an ITEM in the CATEGORY PAGE, the user should be directed to the item's profile page, which is basically the SUBCATEGORY PAGE.  This is where the /?id=$id part comes in.  During the transition phase from category page to subcategory page, the query string should attach itself to the URL and the subcategory page will output data based on the data that is in the database for that specific item.  For instance, if a user clicked on a link such as this: www.mysite.com/category/subcategory/?id=12, the user should be directed to the profile page of the item with the id of 12.  The profile page, which is the subcategory page in our case, should output data for the item in the database that has the id of 12.  That's how it should work.  The subcategory page, or item profile page, will have a $_GET code so that it knows what data it is suppose to output.

Comment: So, you've got a working them. Tear it apart and find out how it does this. Then come back and post your results here, so we can learn too.

Comment: Pretty sure you mean query string and query parameter not SQL...

Comment: Do *not* post a duplicate question, edit this one instead.  Doing this may result in further moderator action.

Answer (score 1):

#### Revised Answer

Look into WordPress' [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). It's definitely the more "correct" way of doing this.

#### Original Answer

Instead of using a URL query, try something like:

```
// URL: http://blahblahblah.com/category/pagetitle/15

preg_match_all('/[^\/]+/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
$item_id = $matches[0][2];

echo 'Do whatever you want with Item ID ' . $item_id;
```

Comment: What do I put in 'Do whatever you want with Item ID'?  I've got a php code that defines the variables, connects to the database, queries the database table, and then outputs all of the items in the database based on their id.  The php that outputs the items is a while loop that prints the items in this format: <a href="www.site.com/category/page/?itemId=$itemId">$itemName</a>.  No idea how to get wordpress's permalink to work with the string at the end.

Comment: Whatever you want. I cannot see your code. Say you got `?item=$itemid` to work, what were you going to do with `$_GET['item']`? In any case, I've updated my answer to suggest a more WordPressy way of doing what you want.

Comment: Example: Go to http://www.rpgmax.com/mmo/gamedirectory and click on any of the items you see in the list.  Each item has a /?gameId=XX query string attached to its URL, however when you click on the item, the server directs you to the /gamedirectory/gameprofile page without leaving the query string attached.  However, if you go to http://www.mmocraze.com/game-directory, the items in the page will leave the query string attached to the URL when you are directed to the game profile page.  I've got this code on the game profile page on both sites: $gameId = $_GET['gameId'];

Comment: I'm not sure how my buddy got the code to work on mmocraze.  I downloaded the files from the file directory on to my computer and a did a "within the file" search for the tag 'gameId' and I couldn't find any signs of wordpress code used. No functions or classes called.  Nothing in htaccess that suggested URL rewrite, nothing special in permalink structure.  It confuses me.  For some crazy reason, the URL query string just seems to work on mmocraze but not rpgmax.

Answer (score 0):

> If a user clicks on an item in the list, the user gets directed to the
>   subcategory page without the sql string attached.

What do you mean exactly with "sql string"?

Could you describe, as concrete as possible, what links you have, examples and what page they should direct to and what those pages should do?

Also: I get the feeling you're a little out of your depth here and you're doing stuff with the database based on parameters from the URL . You should know that manipulating URL parameters to gain access to a database is a real easy way to hack a site. Please read a little bit about [SQL Injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php) and how to prevent it.

Comment: Obligatory link to the canonical comic-strip based SQL injection prevention site: http://bobby-tables.com/